Why was the content of the tag descriptions reduced?
It seems like the content of the tag descriptions was reduced. E.g. when I open a question containing a JSON tag and hover the tag, I can only read "JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a serializable data interchange format intended to be machine- and human-readable."
I have to click the tag to be able to read the whole description "JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a serializable data interchange format that is a machine and human readable. Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals. Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."
That's new. Before, I was able to read the whole description in the question, when I hovered the tag. Important details are missing now. Is this a bug?
